# JavaScript Local File Access And Open File

Tags: javascript, silverlight, file, local

I have currently built basically a copy of Windows explorer using Silverlight 4, to replace part of a client side program that is being converted to work in a browser. This is working fine for uploading files, but some of the users of this program are very computer illiterate, and want to be able to use it the exact same as the client program.

So when they double click the file opens and they can make changes and save it the same as any other file on your computer, without having to download, open make changes and then upload again.

I am currently hoping I will be able to do this with Silverlight 5 trusted in browser, but I would like to know if there is any other possible ways to do this???

**

Comment: Your scenario is confusing, you talk of "Local File Access" and also of downloading and uploading.  Please use more detail, what are these files, what program manipulates them, where are they stored, where is the directory of the available files maintained, etc.

Comment: Hi AnthonyWJones 
I need to keep all the files saved on the server, so if a users wants to edit a file for example a word document, I want to upload a copy of the file to a temp location on the users machine open it with the what ever program is associated with .doc files on the users computer, and then scan the file while the browser is open and upload the file back to the server if it is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't acheive what you have outlined with SL4.  You can with SL5 but even that requires some "setup" on the client, which is best delivered in a Group Policy.

It might be worth you asking yourself what the impact would be on your ability to deliver the functionality if you limited your system requirements to Windows platforms with .NET 3.5 installed.  If the impact is acceptable then you could use Group Policy to deliver a simple WPF app that does this job and you could that now.